# dtmf dial recording for playback to bypass automated dial-in systems

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm looking for an app that would offer the ability to (among other things) record your dtmf key presses into a sort of recording or macro.  The reason behind this would be to go through calling a 1-800 number and pressing various sequences of:

```
1,3,0,# etc
```

till you get a live person.  Obviously the ability to "pause" for a certain amount of time will also needed to be added.

Does something like this exist? If not how hard would it be to make an app that does this function?

Comment: Would programming those pauses into the existing dialer suit your purpose?

Comment: I suppose what do you mean by a dialer though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Contacts app allows pauses and waits to be programmed into phone numbers.

With the number input pad visible, press the *special characters* key on the lower left.

This will reveal options to input 2 second **pauses** (you can use multiple pauses to increase the time) or to **wait** until the dial key is pressed again.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to record it like a macro though?

Comment: What would a macro do that dialing the number from contacts wouldn't?

Comment: @grgarside I appreciate your downsizing the images—I did the entire post via iPad and "forgot" the appropriate width (it's a service on my Mac). However, with the white background screens I'm not sure side-by-side works well here. I'm leaving it as is for now, but I think without image borders it's somewhat confusing.

Comment: I indicated in my question that I would want to program the ability to skip the automated msgs when you call businesses.  Having this as a macro would do this I believe.

Comment: I do this all the time when I dial businesses using the built-in dialer. I "skip" the automated messages by hitting the dial button (again) after waits.  If you trust the timing, you could use pauses instead. I'm sorry, I did read what you said originally, but I don't see why the built-in dialer doesn't provide the functionality you're looking for.